# assembleDebug also generating release assets

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My goal is to have different google-services.json for each buildType. I'm using fastlane to manage the different builds. When i now execute my fastlane dev command, it fails because i don't have any google-services.json file in the release folder.

This is my fastlane script for building the debug build:

```
  desc "Clean, build development release"
  lane :dev do |options|
    if options[:clean]
      clean_android
    end
    rntest
    test
    gradle(
      task: "assemble", 
      build_type: "debug", 
      project_dir: "./")
  end
```

when i execute fastlane dev, i get following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
>
> > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.     Searched Location:
> >     /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/android/app/src/release/google-services.json
> >     /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/android/app/google-services.json

As you can see it is looking for google-services.json in the release folder. The weird thing is, that in my log output i can see that it already parsed the google-services.json in the debug folder correctly. it somehow also triggers all the release generaters after debug:

> :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugGoogleServices Parsing json file:
>   /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   :app:mergeDebugResources :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets Scanning folders
>   for symlinks in
>   /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/node_modules
>   (23ms) Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/node_modules
>   (21ms) Loading dependency graph, done. warning: the transform cache
>   was reset. bundle: start bundle: finish bundle: Writing bundle output
>   to:
>   /Users/appfoundry/Documents/GitHub/afst18gv/DigitalReceptionist/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle
>   bundle: Done writing bundle output bundle: Copying 8 asset files
>   bundle: Done copying assets :app:processDebugResources
>   :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not
>   incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   :app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE :app:assembleDebugUnitTest
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:testDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE :app:checkReleaseManifest
>   :app:prepareReleaseDependencies :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processReleaseGoogleServices FAILED

As you can see here, it does all kind of release things after debug is done.

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInRelease: true,
    bundleInDebug: false,
    bundleInStaging: true,
]



apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.appfoundry.digitalreceptionist"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        def env = System.getenv()
        versionName "1.0.0." + env['BUILD_NUMBER']
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword "afst18gv"
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword "afst18gv"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        staging {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    // From node_modules
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    // Firebase dependencies
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```